# dictionary question in python regarding leetcode#160

Tags: python, linked-list

This is a leetcode question 160. intersection of two linked list, where Given the heads of two singly linked-lists headA and headB, return the node at which the two lists intersect.
https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/

if map[headB]==1 is giving a runtime error in Leetcode.
I know if i use 'if headB in map' it works fine, but i want to know why 'if map[headB]==1' gives error. Thank you.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        map=dict()
        
        while (headA):
            map[headA]=1
            headA=headA.next
        
        while (headB):
            if map[headB]==1: #why this doesn't work? ('if headB in map' works fine)
                return headB
            headB=headB.next
        
        return None
```

Comment: Why would you think the two expressions are the same?

Comment: well technicially they are different. Though both are checking if the headB exists in the dictionary. so i am wondering why only 'headB in map' works

Comment: It's also important  to show what the error is; don't make anyone guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if key headB doesn't exist in map, map[headB] will throw a KeyError.
It cannot compare something that doesn't exist to one.

Also, you might want to use some other name than just "map", because it shadows the built-in Python function map().